# Windows 10 - Only External Monitor Sleeps

Tags: windows-10, display, external-display

I am trying to run a digital signage solution off of an all-in-one. More or less, the computer is playing a slideshow continuously. The computer is connected (via a displayport->VGA adapter) to a TV. The screen contents are duplicated.

This works fine, for a while, but eventually - it seems to be around an hour, but I haven't timed it yet - the TV no longer get an input. But the computer is still playing the slideshow. It is as if only one monitor goes to sleep. The computer itself is configured to never sleep or turn its display off.

What setting might cause this? Any ideas how to fix it?